# Method with throws Exception: Where is it actually handled?

Tags: java, android, exception

Here is an example code, I am throwing an exception here, it works perfectly fine without the try/catch block of code for some reason.

Do I have to handle this inside this method "EntryDelete"
or 
Do I have to handle this where the method is called from?
If so can I see an example, what do I have to import in there? What is the acceptable syntax or method to do this?

```
public boolean EntryDelete(int entryId) throws SQLException{
    this.open();
    kDatabase.delete(kENTRY_TABLE, kENTRY_ENTRY_ID + "=" + entryId, null);
    this.close();
    return true;            
}
```

Edit: Whats the thought on handling the exception in both inside and outside the method?

Whats the benefits of handling inside the method, whats the benefits of handling it outside of the method?

Thanks

Comment: The advantage is simple, it forces the caller to catch the possible exception and in theory, leads to better code.  However, `e.printStackTrace()` seems to be the average exception handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thrown exception is handled (thrown further or caught) by the caller of this method here, not this method itself. Of course, you could handle it here as well by adding the try-catch here, but as it currently is your method forces the caller to handle the possibly thrown exception.

In response to your added question:

"Whats the benefits of handling inside the method, whats the benefits of handling it outside of the method?"

Sadly, the most comprehensive correct answer I can think of is that the advantage of dealing with the exception inside the method is not having to deal with it outside the method. In general, the sooner you handle the exception the better, because you don't usually want to force anyone calling your methods to prepare for any exceptions that aren't strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Since the method has

```
throws SQLException
```

in the signature so the method calling this method will have to handle the exception.

EDIT: There is no rule of thumb, but [from](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html) you can use the following guideline

If the client can take some alternate action to recover from the exception, then throw the exception. If the client cannot do anything useful, handle the exception. By useful, I mean taking steps to recover from the exception and not just logging the exception.